# В C# есть оператор импликации (логического следования)?

Tags: c#, логика, информатика, логические-выражения

Не могу найти, как записать оператор импликации C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нет**, в C# нет встроенного оператора импликации. Его можно реализовать с помощью стандартных операторов:
Импликация: `!a || b`,
Обратная импликация: `a || !b`.
*Дополнительно:* [операторы C# на msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/).